# User is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::642045430519:role/service-role/testPython-role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am starting to work on AWS Lambda, and I am totally new to it. I have been assigned **LambdaFullAccess** policy to work on Lambda.

I am trying to create a sample function that used python 3.11. Whenever I try to create the functions, it shows the following error:

[image]

Is not the above policy enough to work on Lambda? If not, what other policies do I need for Lambda to work fully? I have the following policies attached to my account.

[image]

The policy must make me work on lambda without facing any issues. Thanks

Comment: You don't have permission to create a new IAM role. Is there an existing IAM role that already provides the permissions needed for your Lambda function?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily an issue with working on Lambda. When you are creating your Lambda function you decided to create a new IAM role as the execution role (this becomes the permissions which Lambda has), which is different that the role you use to create the function.

The exception is self explanatory, you need to have the IAM permissions `iam:CreateRole`, however your role only has IAMReadOnlyAccess permissions which is noy adequate.

More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#creds-policies-users

Alternatively, if you already have a role created in your account which has adequate permissions to achieve what the Lambda needs to do, then you can simply select that role as the execution role instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Could you please guide what other permissions do I need so that I could get them all at once?

Comment: Did you read the link I shared, it's there for you.